# indirect reference for sum a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I want to have a sum formula in a cell such as `=SUM(Ex:Ey)` while `E` is the column and `x` and `y` are row numbers. Is there a way I can have excel to match `x` and `y` to the numbers in other cells? For example: cell `D1=3` and `D2=12` and there are many numbers in column `E`. By the end of column `E`, I want to have a cell that sum only the rows from the numbers of `D1` to `D2`, which is sum of `E3` to `E12` in this example. The idea is that I can change `D1` and `D2` to change what rows in column I want to sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT` to reference a range using a constructed string address - `SUM(INDIRECT("E"&D1&":E"&D2))`.

`"E"&D1&":E"&D2` will give you the string "E3:E12" in your example, which `INDIRECT` will then convert to a reference to that actual range.

Note that `INDIRECT` comes with a recalculation overhead, but will be fine if you aren't doing too many of them or too complex things!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to use the sumif formula or sumifs for multiple conditions. This works better in some situations and can be easier to read and audit\review.